# Vue.js - Recompute computed property in a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I searched this problem a lot with no direct answer found.
I have a computed property that depends also on the window height so I need it to be recomputed every time the window is resized. Tried using `$forceUpdate()` but I think it doesn't work with components. Here is my component :

```
Vue.component('trades-component', {

  mixins: [tradingMixin],

  created: function() {
    var that = this;
    // recompute visible trades if window resized
    $( window ).on( "resize", function() {
      that.$forceUpdate();
    });
    $( window ).resize();
  },

  computed: {

    visibleTradesCount: function() {
      var colOffset = $(".left-col").offset();
      var colHeight = $(".left-col").height();
      var tableOffset = $(".left-col #trade-history table").offset();
      var tableHeight = colHeight - (tableOffset.top - colOffset.top) - this.rowHeight;
      return Math.floor(tableHeight / this.rowHeight)
    }
  }
})
```

I know possible workarounds but want to know if there is a way to force recomputing a particular property or all computed properties in components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't as clean as @BillCriswell's answer, but if your computed has other dependencies that trigger a refresh (e.g a data change), you may want to stick with a computed.

You can force a recalc on resize by using data properties for window width and height, and adding a reference to them in your computed property.

```
data: function () {
  return { 
    windowWidth: 0,
    windowHeight: 0
  }
}
created: function() {
  var that = this;
  $( window ).on( "resize", function() {
    that.windowWidth =  window.innerWidth;
    that.windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  });
  $( window ).resize();
},
computed: {
  visibleTradesCount: function() {
    const x = this.windowWidth;
    const y = this.windowHeight;
    ...
```

Note, you may need to `$(window).off("resize"` in `beforeDestroy()`.

Comment: Having a property that is updated on window resize and make the computed value depend on it is the best answer I found. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a computed property for this because you're not updating anything Vue is observing. You can move `visibleTradesCount` from `computed` to `methods` and do:

```
$(window).on('resize', this.visibleTradesCount).resize()
```

Just make sure to debounce the resize event. Also, you should really look into accomplishing this without JavaScript.

Comment: Suggestion: have a data item for window size that is updated by a debounced function. Then the computed and anything else can depend on that.

Comment: Your solution Bill would be perfect if the computed value only depends on the event not other properties Vue observes for changes. On the other hand I find @Roy J comment is what I was looking for. A brilliant idea! if it was an answer not a comment I'd definitely mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: What do you mean by "accomplishing this without JavaScript"? Did you maybe want to write "accomplishing this without jQuery"?